# Error: Cannot allocate an object of abstract type in Qt Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, qt-creator, background-subtraction

I am working on a simple background subtraction. Here is my code

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

//global variables
int history = 1;
float varThreshold = 16;
bool bShadowDetection = true;

Mat src; //source image
Mat fgMaskMOG2; //fg mask generated by MOG2 method
Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> pMOG2; //MOG2 Background subtractor

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //create GUI windows
    namedWindow("Source");
    namedWindow("FG Mask MOG 2");

    src = imread("bluePaper1.png", 1);

    //create Background Subtractor objects
    pMOG2 = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history, varThreshold, bShadowDetection); //MOG2 approach
    pMOG2->setInt("nmixtures", 3);
    pMOG2->setDouble("fTau", 0.5);

    pMOG2->operator()(src, fgMaskMOG2);

    imshow("Source", src);
    imshow("FG Mask MOG 2", fgMaskMOG2);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

but I am getting an error

> cannot allocate an object of abstract type'cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2'

at line `pMOG2 = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history, varThreshold, bShadowDetection); //MOG2 approach`

Comment: Has anyone an idea how I could deal with this?

Comment: you seem to use opencv2.4 code with [opencv3](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/de/de1/group__video__motion.html)

Comment: @berak how do I fix it